# Passing table type to select stored procedure and using LIKE

Tags: sql-server

I never used before table types. I want to pass values from table type dn_test1_typex to a stored procedure which SELECT WHERE LIKE.
It's possible? INNER JOIN method is very slow on my db.
(I expect sp to produce:  xxxpifxxx - volion - nax)
Thank you.

procedure  dn_xx

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[dn_xxx]    Script Date: 6/19/2018 12:43:35 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dn_xxx]
(
    @TableVar dn_test1_typexy READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT  * FROM dn_test2
   WHERE col1a like(not IN) (SELECT col1 from @TableVar)

END
```

table dn_test2

```
 INSERT INTO dn_test2(col1a,col2a,col3a)
    VALUES ('xxxpifxxx','volion','nax'),
        ('der','ter','byt')
```

---

table type dn_test1_typex

```
DECLARE @TableVar dn_test1_typexy

    INSERT INTO @TableVar(col1,col2,col3)
    VALUES ('pif','ion','frt'),
        ('rik','def','bui') 


exec dn_xx @TableVar  >>>    This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
```

Comment: `EXEC dn_xxx @MyTable`. See the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine).

Comment: You dont insert id in @TableVar. `INSERT INTO @TableVar(id,col1,col2,col3)
VALUES ('pif','ion','frt')` but, you are selecting id in the subquery: `WHERE id in (SELECT id from @TableVar)`

Comment: The variable's name is `@TableVar` now, so `EXEC dn_xxx @TableVar`. The point is, invoking the sproc without specifying a parameter will just pass `NULL` for the table. The table is not shared between your session and the stored procedure; you must declare, fill and pass it explicitly.